# Active X controls on Excel 2010 sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with 2 worksheets in it, each with a different active X contol, a command button.
If either worksheet is the active sheet in the only open window, each control works as intended.
If I have the two worksheets as the active sheets in two windows at the same time, the control on one sheet works, the control on the other does not work.
I do not receive any error messages, just nothing happens.
Am I missing something, if so what!

Hello
Sorry for the delay in replying, life (Christmas shopping, everyday stuff etc.) got in the way and I have not had time to look at this recently.
I hope I am doing things right, as I have not used this group before
I have stripped the problem down to a simple example, see below, and it still happens
Create a workbook, I called mine “Test_CommandButtons.xlsm”
Give the workbooks 3 sheets named “One”, “Two” & “Three”
The actual names do not matter, it just makes things easier to follow.
On each worksheet
Create an Active X Control Command Button
Name the command buttons “cmbOne”, cmbTwo” & “CmbThree” etc
ie the command button name is “cmb” followed by the Sheet Name.
Paste the following code below into each of the cmb_Click routines

Const TabA As Integer = 5
Const TabB As Integer = 25

```
Debug.Print
Debug.Print Now()
Debug.Print Tab(TabA); "Window Caption: "; Tab(TabB); ActiveWindow.Caption
Debug.Print Tab(TabA); "Sheet Name: "; Tab(TabB); ActiveSheet.Name
Debug.Print Tab(TabA); "Control Name:"; Tab(TabB); ActiveSheet.OLEObjects(1).Name
Debug.Print Tab(TabA); "Control Caption:"; Tab(TabB); ActiveSheet.OLEObjects(1).Object.Caption
```

With only one open window open, any sheet will give the expected result ie with one window open, containing sheet one, clicking the command button “Button One” will print

11/12/2021 13:35:11
Window Caption:     Test_CommandButtons.xlsm
Sheet Name:         One
Control Name:       cmbOne
Control Caption:    Button One

With 2 or more windows open, irrespective of which workbook is active in the windows. the only command button that will react is the one in window 1 i.e. using my nomenclature “Test_CommandButtons.xlsm:1”

Comment: This also happens in Excel 2021. Form controls work OK if that helps.

Comment: Have you looked at the code behind the button at all?  Would you be able to share it here as an edit to the question?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.